# List<Object> as a JRBeanCollectionDataSource to a Subreport

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm passing a List as a JRBeanCollectionDataSource to a Subreport. Here Object is of Type **`A`** and **`B`**. The object type **`A`** has two properties: ***`name`*** and ***`address`*** and the object type **`B`**  has the ***`location`*** property.

If Object is of type **`A`** then I have to display ***`name`*** and ***`address`*** in subreport. And if it is of type **`B`** then I have to display ***`location`*** in subreport.

I have to access a type of Object in a subreport, means is of which type (**`A`** or **`B`**)?. 
I have tried a lot but not found any solution.

Can anyone help me please.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have many options:

**First:** Put a flag field in both objects stating is this Object A or Object B.
Then in `Subreport Expression` use a ternary statement like this:

```
objectType=="ObjectA"?"subreportA.jasper":"subreportB.jasper"
```

**Second:** Pass the sub report name as a field inside the object itself.
Then in `Subreport Expression` use the field like:

```
$F{subReportName}
```

**Third:** Make two subreports each is populated by its own type. If you want to show "Subreport A" then populate ObjectA and leave ObjectB list as null. In Jasper, if the populating list is `NULL`, the subreport is not rendered.