# How to pass a list of objects from a Java application to the sub-report?

Tags: jasper-reports, report, reporting

I have a report with one bar chart and one table. these two elements are filled by the list of objects which is passed from my *Java* application to the report.

Now I want to put these two elements in two different *sub-reports*, but I do not know how I can pass the list of objects to the sub-reports. I have added the fields of each object as a field in master report and as a parameter in sub-report, but it does not work.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass ArrayList to JasperReports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624562/how-to-pass-arraylist-to-jasperreports) & [List<Object> as a JRBeanCollectionDataSource to a Subreport](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2735497/876298) & [Passing data to subreport](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7080527/876298) & [How to pass a List of JRBeanCollectionDataSource to a subreport](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13384698/876298)

Comment: Did you try to search on SO?

Comment: Question is not clear. Are you want pass all values of dataSource (list of objects) to subreport? 
What are you want to display in subreport?
What mean "Now I want to put these TWO elements in two different sub-reports"? You have only one list of objects...

Comment: sanBez, I want to have one sub-report with table and one sub-report with bar chart. theses two sub-reports show the same thing in different way. The master report has two subreport element. I don't know how I have to set the properties in order to fill the master report.

Comment: Alex K, thanks for your suggestions, but I couldn't find my answer in those links.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

Pass collection into main report as parameter and use this parameter in DataSource for subreports:

// java-code for main report

```
JRBeanCollectionDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listOfObject);
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("myList", listOfObject);
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, ds);
```

// end java-code

(may be

```
JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, new JREmptyDataSource())
```

if you don't need to display data in main report)

Define in main.jrxml report parameter myList as java.util.Collection

Add subreports into main report (into summary band) 
Set in main report for subreports properties: 
Connection type = Use a datasource expression 
Data Source Expression = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{myList})

Define in subreports desired field (based on listOfObjects).

Comment: sanBez, I did whatever you have explained, but I got the following error when I clicked the preview button: Cannot instantiate the type JRDataSource. Do you know what I have to do?

Comment: show me DataSource Expression.
And see for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960149/cannot-instantiate-the-type-listproduct

Comment: sanBez thanks a lot for your help. I put $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE} for Data Source Expression of each sub-report. Do I have to change anything in Parameters or Parameters Map Expression properties of them? Also, do I have to define a parameter in each sub-report? I have put my bar chart in title band of subreport1 and my table in detail band of subreport2.

Comment: In my test report $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE} is not work in this case. 
Change DataSourceExpression to new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{myList})

Comment: In some cases you can use $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE} but not in this report (imho).
If you will use $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE} for table, then the first record will be lost in the subreport table